# Find all cycles in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I found a question on how to find cycle in an undirected graph. The solution to the problem was

```
bool dfs(int x)
{
    state[x] = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < ls[x].size(); j++)
    {
        if(state[ls[x][j]] == 1 and parent[x] != ls[x][j])
        {
            if(t)
            {
                printf("Cycle entry: %d\n", ls[x][j]);
                printf("Cycle contains: %d, %d ", ls[x][j], x);
                int cycleNode = parent[x];
                while(cycleNode != ls[x][j])
                {
                    printf("%d ", cycleNode);
                    cycleNode = parent[cycleNode];
                }
            }
            t = 0;
            return t;
        }
        if(state[ls[x][j]] == 0)
        {
            parent[ls[x][j]] = x;
            dfs(ls[x][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do i modify it in order to find all the cycle that there are in the graph and not just one as the DFS above do. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Note that there can be exponentially many simple cycles in a graph. Unless your graph is somehow special so that there are not that many, you can just use brute force to find them all.

Comment: It's not easy to help you on this one without knowing what e.g. `state`, `parent`, `ls` etc. are. Maybe add a link to the original question for context?

Comment: @Gassa: That a graph with `n` nodes can contain a number of simple cycles which is exponentian in `n` was my first reflex too, however I have no idea how a suitable class of graphs would look like. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Gassa: Ok, I found it out. Nevermind.